# Объединить метки [слайдер] и [slider]

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, метки, синонимы-меток

Предлагаю объединить данные метки, так как это одно и то же, только на разных языках.
У метки [slider](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slider) 240 вопросов (на момент просмотра), а метка [слайдер](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80) насчитывает 34 вопроса (на момент просмотра). Я сторонник сделать русскоязычную метку основной, так как сообщество у нас соответствующее, но это уже надо решать нам коллективно. Также на данный момент у обоих нет описания. Метка достаточно популярная и вряд-ли в ближайшем будущем станет ненужной.

**UPDATED**

Добавил краткое описание русскоязычной метки.

Comment: А можете, пожалуйста, исправить описание метки [tag:слайдер]? Потому что это по сути ползунок https://i.stack.imgur.com/LS0Ye.jpg и чаще всего так именно и используется, особенно в англ. языке. К примеру, https://api.jqueryui.com/slider/ Судя по описанию, многие его путают с каруселью. Если можно укажите об этом в описании, что для показа совокупности картинок используйте метку [tag:карусель]. Я бы, может, и сам сделал, но не силён в описаниях…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Влад, хоть сообщество и русское, но все ЯП на английском в большинстве. Даже плагины и те на английском. Я посмотрел метки и те на которых есть слайдер, в большинстве своем имеют по 3-4 метки на английском. Либо люди просто ленятся, либо настолько безграмотны. Просто исправлять метку на slider и все.

Comment: Это лишь предложение, я сам в большинстве случаев предпочитаю английский и последние прочитанные мною книги, и документация были англоязычными. Все упирается в знания, точнее в уровень усвоения / понимания языка на данный момент времени (так как без практики знания языка, как и всего другого утекают как вода сквозь сито). Я лишь предположил, что коль сообщество русскоязычное, то возможно необходимо сделать информацию доступной более широкой аудитории (даже той, у которой английский пока большая проблема).

Comment: Я предлагаю использовать англоязычное название. Автор ответа описал все отлично. Все ЯП (ну кроме 1С) используют латинские буквы и английский язык. И это будет логично. И легче будет подобные вопросы переводить.

Comment: Поддерживаю, лучше в английском исполнение! Лучше иметь единый стандарт, а то таким темпом можно докатиться и до того, что будут использовать Китайский, Немецкий, Испанские языки, а оно нннадо?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** Не годится, слайдер - это ползунок, а не карусель.

А что если основной сделать метку [карусель](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%83%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c)?

Comment: Я на 100% не уверен, но для карусели точно можно добавить синоним [tag:carousel].

Comment: Нет, так точно нельзя. Вот это элемент управления, который ездит туда-сюда https://api.jqueryui.com/slider/ К примеру, для выбора численных значений.

Comment: То есть слайдером называют иногда (по ошибке) карусель. На enSO в описании [tag:slider] принято то, что это эл-т управления, а карусель — отдельно. Уверен, что нам так и надо сделать. Иначе будет путаница, поэтому предлагаю просто синонимизировать дословные переводы.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, да, согласен.

Comment: @Qwertiy вперёд.