# Объединить метки [button] и [кнопка]

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, метки, синонимы-меток

Стоит объединить [button](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/button) и [кнопка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b0).

[button](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/button) - [369 вопросов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/button).

[кнопка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b0) - [3 вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B0).

Следует ли подобные метки на английском переводить на русский язык в соответствии со [словарём](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1268/317064)?

Comment: [Связанный вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/292/317064)

Comment: @VladSpirin но ведь можно перенести описание в `кнопка` и сделать её основной, т.к. она на русском языке

Comment: [Глянь сюда](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7152/262779), я тоже как-то проталкивал подобную мысль. Жди мнения сообщества по этому поводу

Comment: Хотя с кнопкой должно быть проще, тут понятие одно - `кнопка`, а в том моем случае, можно было еще велосипеды прикручивать.

Comment: В предложениях по объединению меток не забывайте указывать какую метку предлагается сделать основной и почему. Это не всегда очевидно.

Comment: @älёxölüt я специально поставил метки и `обсуждение`, и `предложение`, чтобы "предложить объединить" и "обсудить основную" :)

Comment: Видимо, это тоже оказалось недостаточно очевидным :)

Comment: @VladSpirin не сделаете. Там надо помимо общей репы ещё иметь голоса по конкретной метке.

Comment: @VladSpirin чью и куда выдвигать?

Comment: @VladSpirin а что уже выборы какие-то начались? КМ (которого нет) не считает необходимым, имхо.

Comment: но ведь есть к примеру, `arduino`.. Вопросы по нему вполне вписываются в сообщество. Ну  например у кого-то пробелы при подключении  "тактовой кнопки". Хотя в таком вопросе наверно кнопка не заслуживает отдельной метки, но всё же. `button` будет точно не к месту там.

Answer (score 5):

У метки [button](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/button) есть полное описание. Так как вопросов по метке [кнопка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b0), было всего три, я перенес их в основную [button](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/button). Предлагаю поддержать автора и синонимизировать метки, чтоб их не плодили новые пользователи. В качестве основной предлагаю установить устоявшуюся в сообществе [button](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/button).